# How to configure code formatting for .mjml file in PhpStorm editor

Tags: phpstorm, code-formatting, mjml

I'm using [mjml](https://mjml.io/) to create a mailer template with `npm` and using [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) as my IDE.

But for some reason my code isn't visually formatting in html which doesn't make it easy to build templates.

[image]

Is there any way to configure custom file types in PhpStorm like `.mjml` to run html formatted code rather than plain text?

Comment: Good discussion at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000238699-MJML-reformat-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What language type do you have `.mjml` files associated with in *File | Settings | Editor | File Types*? They should be assigned to HTML by the looks of it.
[image]